# How we edit Word Document (docx,xlsx,ppt) and pdf file in iOS app

Tags: ios, pdf, ms-word

I am an iOS developer I want to make an App in which I can view and edit `pdf` and document (`docx,xlsx,ppt`) files. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Hi did you get any solution for editing pdf?

Answer (score 1):

The `UIDocumentInteractionController` class or `QLPreviewController` class can be used for the same purpose.

I hope these tutorials help you:

- [iOS SDK: Previewing and Opening Documents](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130)
- [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS: About Document Interaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

May be this library
 will help you http://libopc.codeplex.com/documentation